# Error de conversión List<SelectListItem> a Ienumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

Estoy intentando crear un selectlist de un conjunto de categorías. He usado el debug desde la capa de acceso a datos para obtener la traza de que los datos llegan correctos hasta llegar a la vista.

El problema es que la vista me suelta un tipo de error porque parece que intenta convertir un SelectListItem en Ienumerable

este es el modelo de categorías

```
 public class CatProfesionalModel
    {
        public int IdCat { get; set; }
        public string NombreCat { get; set; }

        public CatProfesionalModel()
        {

        }

        public CatProfesionalModel(DataRow row)
        {
            this.IdCat = row.Field<int>("ID_CatProfesional");
            this.NombreCat = row.Field<string>("NombreCat");
        }

    }
```

Este modelo genera una lista de SelectListItem

```
public class TiposCatProfesional
    {
       public List<SelectListItem> CatProfessionalSelectList { get; set; }

    }
```

Esta es la operación que realizo en la capa de dominio.

```
public TiposCatProfesional ObtenerCatProfesional()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = datUsuarios.ObtenerCatProfesional();
            
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            TiposCatProfesional tiposCatProfessional = new TiposCatProfesional();
            tiposCatProfessional.CatProfessionalSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<CatProfesionalModel> catProfesional = new List<CatProfesionalModel>();

            //Se carga una lista de Categorias profesionales
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                catProfesional.Add(new CatProfesionalModel(item));
            }
            //Se usa la lista de categorias profesionales para cargar la lista de SelectListItem
            foreach (var item in catProfesional)
            {
                tiposCatProfessional.CatProfessionalSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.NombreCat, 
                                                                    Value = item.IdCat.ToString() });
            }

            return tiposCatProfessional;
                        
        }
```

Lo que realiza el controlador

```
public IActionResult CreateUser()
        {
            TiposCatProfesional tiposCatProfesional = new TiposCatProfesional();
//Obtenemos el objeto TipoCatProfesional relleno que viene de la capa de dominio
            tiposCatProfesional = usuarios.ObtenerCatProfesional();
            return View(tiposCatProfesional);
        }
```

Y esto es lo que intento colocar en la vista.

```
@model STControlHorario.TiposCatProfesional`

<select asp-items="Model.CatProfessionalSelectList" class="form-select"></select>
```

En la vista me genera este error  CS0266 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' en 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)``

Quiero que la vista muestre el objecto select con sus respectivos SelectListItem. como puedo solventar este error?
Espero podáis echarme una mano.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Todo parece apuntar a que System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem =/= Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem Tienes 2 clases distintas con el mismo nombre

Comment: Para entenderlo un mejor dónde está residiendo el problema? En el modo de llamar a la librería en using?

Comment: Claro, lo que entiendo (sin estar 100% seguro), es que tus listas tienen dentro elementos de distintas clases. Porque hay varias clases que se repiten en su nombre pero el namespace es distinto. Entonces en tu clase `TiposCatProfesional` estas ocupando un `SelectListItem ` que viene del namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` y en el otro lado ocupas el que viene de `System.Web.Mvc`  (o viceversa)

Comment: Efectivamente. Al trabajar por capas tengo dos namespace diferentes al namespace que crea MVC. Estos dos namespace son la capa de servicio o dominio y el otro namespace es la capa de soporte. La cual aloja todos los modelos.  Ambos namespace diferentes a MVC usan ```System.Web.Mvc``` y el objeto que uso en el controlador de MVC viene de ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering```. Entiendo que haciendo que todos sean de un mismo using se solucionaría el problema, pero como podría hacer para usar ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering``` fuera de MVC?

Comment: He podido solucionar el problema. Al parecer en los espacios de nombre hay que desinstalar el paquete NuGet que se instalo a la hora de seleccionar '''SelectListItem''' eliminando una instalacion de '''System.Web.Mvc''' e indicarle que instale el paquete '''Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering''' Gracias por la ayuda facilitada! @yussef